# Download a application from AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, download, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How can I download a application from Elastic Beanstalk?
I uploaded the application via the web interface, and made some changes live (It's a wordpress site), and now I want to download the whole site.

Comment: Since it is a wordpress site does that mean you have a database configured too? Do you just want to download the source code or the configuration changes as well?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can download the site from within Application Versions Table (Source Column) in AWS Console.

- Log into AWS Console
- Navigate to Services-> Beanstalk -> Application Versions

Alternatively you can also scp the file from the EC2 instance tied to your beanstalk application.

Answer (score 19):

Using the CLI EB client you can run from your application's local directory:

```
eb labs download
```

It will download the application's last version code archive into `./.elasticbeanstalk/downloads/<some name with numbers>.zip`

Answer (score 0):

1. Log into the aws console.
2. Search for "Elastic Beanstalk".
3. Select the Environment.
4. Choose Application Versions on the left side bar.
5. Select the Application version that you want to download by clicking on the link in the source column.
6. Wait for download to complete.