# AWS - Download Current Site With User Content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a way to download the current site content, namely, **the uploaded user images**, from a web application on AWS? Everything I have found only gives access to previous code deployments, which do not include the user uploaded files.

I have tried the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234574/download-a-application-from-aws-elastic-beanstalk) but it only seems to give access to the code as it was at the time of deployment.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

User uploaded images are usually stored in Amazon's S3 service, so go to your AWS dashboard and navigate to the S3 section, and you should find the files in a bucket there

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. I thought what was in the bucket looked like the same deployments though but I'll recheck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to download your own website ? Then you need to get not just code or user images; but also database containing data. You need to check the code where images are saved.. Are they on local EBS or EFS or S3 and correspondingly copy from there.

If you are trying to download some-one else website. Then surely you will not have access to database or code or other user images; but still you can download full website as seen to the public using many tools like WinHTTrack.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have full access to AWS but this is an inherited web application and my first time using AWS.

Comment: Sure.. So, you need to migrate it to somewhere else ? Then as I mentioned get copy of database also.

Comment: Yes and no. I have the code from a git repository and I have full access to the SQL database, it's just a matter of getting what media has interactively been put onto the site by users since it has been deployed and public.